# Protractor - Page object: Failed: is not a function

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, pageobjects

I'm working with Protractor and I create a page object.

This is my page object:

```
'use strict';

var CreateAgent = function () {
this.agentEmail = element(by.model('agent.email'));
this.janrainConsoleAgent = by.xpath(".//*[@value='ccp_agent']");
this.janrainConsoleAgentManager = by.xpath(".//* .[@value='ccp_agent_manager']");
this.saveButton = by.className('md-primary md-raised md-button md-ink-ripple');

this.addEmail = function(email){
    this.agentEmail.sendKeys(email);
};

this.selectRole = function(role){
    switch(role){
        case 'ccp agent':
            this.janrainConsoleAgent.click();
        case 'ccp agent manager':
            this.janrainConsoleAgentManager.click();
        default:
            break;
    }
};

this.saveAgent = function(){
    this.saveButton.click();
};
};
module.exports = CreateAgent;
```

This functions are calling in a spec

Here is the spec:

```
var createAgent = require('../page/create_agent_page');

 describe('Protractor Demo Janrain - Create Agent', function(){

    it('should fill out information to create agent', function(){

      createAgent.addEmail('jburquez+auto001@janrain.com');
      browser.sleep(3000);
      createAgent.selectRole('ccp agent manage');
      browser.sleep(3000);
      createAgent.saveAgent();
      browser.sleep(7000);

   });
});
```

but when I execute my test is giving me an error:

```
Failures:
1) Protractor Demo Janrain - Create Agent should fill out information  to create agent
Message:
  Failed: createAgent.addEmail is not a function
Stack:
  TypeError: createAgent.addEmail is not a function
```

I'm not sure if something is missing in the page object or in other place.

Hope you can help me and thanks.

Comment: PageObject pattern: `https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change `module.exports = CreateAgent;` to `module.exports = new CreateAgent();`. You need to create a new instance of CreateAgent function to access all methods inside the function.

Comment: Yea, that was the problem, Thank you @Sudharsan Selvaraj

Answer (score 3):

Exporting an object of page **module.exports = new CreateAgent();** is **NOT a best practice** as an object alive even you do not use it(example-When executing other test spec)

**BEST WAY IS:** Export only Object function **module.exports = CreateAgent;**  and create an object on Spec() where you need that page object. Follow below code:

```
var createAgent = require('../page/create_agent_page');


describe('Protractor Demo Janrain - Create Agent', function(){
var createAgenPageObj;

  beforeAll(function(){
  //create an object for page
  createAgenPageObj=new createAgent ();

    });
  it('should fill out information to create agent', function(){

   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance in your spec file.

For example:

```
var createAgent = new CreateAgent();
```

And access functions using:

```
createAgent.addEmail();
```